# How many fingers are needed for Itadori to be controlled?

Tags: jujutsu-kaisen

In *Jujutsu Kaisen*, how many fingers did Itadori need to consume in order for his soul to be controlled by Sukuna who gave him a chance to live in one of the episodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before Itadori's apparent death, Sukuna consumed 3 fingers:

1. 1 eaten in school in introduction arc
2. 1 eaten after given from Gojo in introduction arc
3. 1 taken by Sukuna after killing finger spirit in cursed womb arc

When Itadori apparently died and Sukuna took over, they made a pact between them. Sukuna calls it "enchaning". According to the pact, Sukuna can only take control of Itadori’s body only for a minute and can't kill or hurt during that minute. However, Itadori doesn't remember he agreed to that and this option hasn't been used.

> So, can Sukuna take over his body permanently?

Sukuna has 20 fingers. If Yuji were to eat all 20 fingers, Sukuna won't be unleashed (currenly there are 147 chapters in manga, so the reason is still yet to be known). Itadori can supress him, and the only way to unleash Sukuna for a little while would be to consume several fingers at once, but after a certain amount of time Itadori would take control again.

Current status:

> [Yuji has consumed 15 fingers as of chapter 147](https://animehunch.com/2021/05/02/sukunas-fingers-everything-you-need-to-know-about-them-in-jujutsu-kaisen/)

Sources (Warning: spoiler links):

1. https://www.quora.com/In-Jujutsu-Kaisen-if-Itadori-consumes-all-20-fingers-will-Sukuna-be-unleashed-having-taken-over-Itadori-s-body-completely
2. https://www.reddit.com/r/JuJutsuKaisen/comments/hk981f/sukunas_fingers_status/
3. https://jujutsu-kaisen.fandom.com/f/p/4400000000000023463