# Where is Sukuna's last finger?

Tags: jujutsu-kaisen

My friend said, that when Geto took Itadori's mom's body, he has fused her baby (Itadori) with one of Sukuna's fingers.

Does it mean Itadori himself is the last finger of Sukuna?

Comment: Related: [How many fingers are needed for Itadori to be controlled?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/62855/how-many-fingers-are-needed/62858)